# How to define permissions based on a model field in Django 2.2/Python 3.5

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom user model with a field that defined the user level. I'd like to use this field to restrict certain views/API endpoints and other functionality.

I.e. for Class-Based views or URL routes, how can I use this property i.e. if user is logged in and is_end_user, then don't allow access to CBV 1, and similar logic?

The roles here, i.e. Admin are not the same as a superuser, so none of these have access to the Django admin backend, but I want to make separate "admin" views/panels for different user groups - also the API should only be accessible by users that are id_end_user == True.

I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.5

**Model definition:**

```
class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    [...]
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            (1, 'appuser'),
            (2, 'moderator'),
            (3, 'intern'),
            (4, 'admin'),
    )
    [...]

    def _get_user_type(self):
            return self.user_type

     @property
        def is_end_user(self):
            if (self._get_user_type() is 1):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to learn how to do something is to see how Django implements it themselves. Here's the [decorators module](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py) for user permissions in Django.

Here's the code for `login_required`:

```
def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

So you should be able to use something like for `is_end_user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME

def end_user_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, redirect_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is an end_user.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_end_user,
        login_url=redirect_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

You may have to tweak this more or even create your own version of `user_passes_test`. However, I'm hopeful this is enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) should do exactly what you need, but, it would be a little more useful to roll your own mixin(s). Here's an example of something similar to what you need.

```
class UserMixin(object):
    allowed_roles = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.allowed_roles:
            if request.role not in self.allowed_roles:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "You don't have permission to view the page requested.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        return super(UserMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Use it like this:

```
class MyViewThatOnlyAdminsShouldSee(LoginRequiredMixin, UserMixin):
    allowed_roles = [AppUser.ADMIN]
```

In my case, I just redirected to the home page of the site with a message. You could also throw a 403 or 404 depending on what your needs are